# Unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datatable' to type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable AVT of type AvailDataTable.  The following code works to create a new datatable from AVT:

```
AvailDataTable AVT1 = (AvailDataTable) AVT.DefaultView.Table;
```

However, the code:

```
AvailDataTable AVT1 = (AvailDataTable) AVT.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

fails with the message "Unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datatable' to type 'AvailDataTable'.

Can someone explain why the first cast works but the second one doesn't?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataView.Table returns you the underlying source DataTable, in your case this source table is of type AvailDataTable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.table.aspx

Whereas DefaultView.ToTable constructs a new instance of a DataTable based on the rows in the current view.

Subtle difference here but ToTable returns you a generic DataTable object not your specific DataTable type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting it.  Does this mean that my original statement is wrong, that in the first case I am not getting a 'new' datatable, just a reference to the original datatable?  And that the second cast doesn't work because the View that is being used to create the new datatable might not have the same columns as the original datatable?

Comment: Hooray!  Progress is being made..slowly.. Thank you.